# can classes have visibility to its namespace only

Tags: php, class, oop, namespaces, visibility

Is it possible to declare a class to be only visible or usable by other classes inside the same namespace?

example:

```
namespace Dirtyredz;
class BikeStore{}
private Class Bike{}
```

I want Bike to only be accessible by BikeStore

Im trying to create a class that handles and manipulates data that needs to be structured in its own class or a structured array. I have read that this may be accomplished by using namespaces but havnt figured that out as of yet.

Comment: The best answer I can give you at the moment is [*not yet*](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/nested_classes)

Comment: Yeah, classes in PHP are always visible to the outside. It would be nice to have a concept of visibility within namespaces (like in Go for instance), but it does not exist currently. Maybe in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PHP Request/Bugs](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=52297)

[PHP Request/Bugs](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=44194)

[PHP Request/Bugs](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=45681)

So from the comments i focused my search and s the comments say, this ability is not present in PHP at the moment. I did read somewhere that it might never be available as the php developers don't think its necessary.

Comment: I think that you could check this answer as answer.

Comment: Had to wait 2 days to answer then forgot completely about it thxs